# gnome: how to lock session on suspend

Tags: gnome, suspend, laptop, session

I'd like to enter my password when I open the lid to access my laptop;
I use GNOME 43 and currently when I close the lid, it goes into suspend state;  then when I open the lid, the laptop resumes and I can simply use it; but this is unsafe;

What option do I need to set?

**UPDATE:** as @don_crissti pointed out in comment, I am unable to lock manually, as well; getting this error:

```
gnome-shell[278269]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
gsd-media-keys[278387]: Couldn't lock screen: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2derror_2dquark.Code24: Timeout was reached
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/disable-lock-screen
true
```

while `/org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/lock-enabled` does not exist

Comment: @don_crissti No, updated OP

Comment: @don_crissti updated OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you confirmed, the screen lock feature was disabled. To fix it, in this particular case, it's only a matter of re-enabling it by running

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/disable-lock-screen false
```

As a general rule, because GNOME settings change often,  you'd run `dconf dump / | grep lock` , most of the keys names are self explanatory, in this case `disable-lock-screen`. There used to be another one called `lock-enabled` that locked the screen automatically when idle... and they're both boolean type, i.e. they're either `true` or `false`.